# Datasheet for Nokia 6310 display

Tags: lcd, datasheet, display, cellphone

I have a Nokia 6310 display which I would like to reuse as a display controlled by an ATMega. I can find plenty of information about N3310 display but almost nothing about 6310.

Does anyone know the type of the display and where to find its specification (pinout, protocol)?

On the metallic cover, there is "01222P02148DS" imprinted and "DMD06868" engraved. On the display itself, there is nothing. The display has 8 pins connected to the rest of telephone.

Any hints are welcome.

UPDATE:
Thanks, in the meantime, I've found http://www.module.ro/nokia_3510.html with more details.

> Nokia 6310 & 6310i lcd pinouts
>
> ```
>     Lcd chip: Philips pcf8511 / pcf8813 (I think - not tested but it looks to be the same lcd driver used in N3510) 
>     Resolution: 96x65 
>     Protocol: SPI 3Wire 
>     Die size: cca. 2,85x10,85 mm 
>     Spare part code: 4850163 
>
>
> Pin8 _Reset
> Pin7 _Cs
> Pin6 Gnd
> Pin5 Sdata
> Pin4 Sclk
> Pin3 Vio  1.8V
> Pin2 Vbooster in  2.7V
> Pin1 Vlcd  (from internal dc/dc converter)
> ```

I'm still unsure about V<sub>lcd</sub> (3.3V?), so I will look for the datasheet and if it works, I'll post the details.

Comment: Goto http://www.8051projects.net/custompages/n6310.php For pinouts and pin numbering, might help!

Answer (score 1):

You can find the pinout for this display and other nokia displays [here](http://www.module.ro/nokia_3510.html) and [here](http://pinouts.ru/CellularPhones-Nokia/nokia_5110_6110_pinout.shtml).